# Keep xscreensaver running

Tags: xscreensaver

Every now and then, xscreensaver dies. When it does, my session unlocks and won't lock until I restart it. Is there a way to automatically detect that xscreensaver has died, restart it, and lock the session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of starting xscreensaver directly, use a wrapper script.

```
#!/bin/sh

prog=xscreensaver

while :
do
   $prog &
   wait
done
```

Run this script as you would xscreensaver, i.e. in the background, launched from .xinitrc or equivalent.  If xscreensaver dies, this script will notice and immediately restart it.

Comment: To make this work properly, I had to add xscreensaver-command -activate after launching the program. Otherwise, if xscreensaver dies in the middle of the night, it will restart, but it won't activate.